# What form of martial arts should I choose?

Tags: kung-fu, recommendation, krav-maga, wing-chun, tai-chi

I'm 20 years old and want to learn a martial art. I have fractured my leg twice in the past, but still I want to try.

Which form should I choose? My physical strength is good, have fast reflexes, can run fast (despite the previous fractures) etc. Does anyone have any advice? I live in India, so many forms may not be available.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I recommend taking a look at the [tour](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I believe this is off-topic, because it's asking for advice on choosing an art, is opinion-based, and is (relatively) localised.

Comment: how can it be off topic? I've given my medical and physical condition. All I needed is what to opt? So, asking for an advice is off topic. If its then this platform is useless which thinks advising someone is off topic.

Comment: @pradeepTuran007 What are your goals? What are you looking to get out of martial arts?

Comment: @pradeepTuran007 And yes, Stack Exchange is in general useless, not only for the reason you described.

Comment: Please take a look at the [tour](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tour) and at the [help page](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about on-topic questions.

Comment: @LastStar007 The only goal is to be in Army. Learning martial art will be plus point in my selection. If I couldn't make it out, I've a backup plan to be Martial Arts trainer and train women in self defense tactics:)

Comment: Please read [A good martial art recommendation question guidelines](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/506/82).

Comment: @Collett89 He literally just said what he wants to get out of martial art.

Comment: yes, pradeepTuran007, asking for advice is off-topic.  That is because the Q&A that results can only benefit one person in the world: you.  that lessens the effectiveness of this site.  Think of it this way: suppose we all agreed on the perfectest martial art for you to take.  What happens when it isn't offered in your area?  What if the instructor is a jerk?  What if you can't afford it?  The reality is that there can be no agreed upon answer, therefore, your question is unhelpful to you, and to the rest of the world who also wants a recommendation.

Comment: @Wigwam - Not quite, but close. The FAQ states "Evaluating and choosing martial arts given specific criteria (e.g. grappling, high kicks, self-defense, etc.)". We can recommend an art *when given the criteria to do so*. This question is rightly closed, although I would have chosen too broad rather than opinion, but that's apples/oranges. There is just nothing here to go on other than "Wanna learn martial something".

Comment: The best option what I found is starting with boxing, then after developing good skills can move to Muay Thai(if fractured leg doesn't create problem) or Krav Maga.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Based on your goal to join the army, Krav Maga will be the most applicable. Krav Maga is oriented towards the kinds of situations you're most likely to find yourself in the military--hand-to-hand, no-holds-barred, where the opponents likely have weapons.

Comment: Why recommend something that might not be available to the OP?  How can you recommend a school without knowing the instructor's qualifications?  Or cost?  Or class schedule?  The OP admitted a health issue; why recommend anything while not knowing his health history?

Comment: Because he tagged Krav Maga. I inferred it was an option since he tagged it. You will notice that I didn't recommend a school, only an art.

Comment: Yes, but also tagged kung fu.  That's not a style, it's a family of styles.  Tai chi also isn't commonly seen today as a MA.  Bottom line, we cannot recommend.  There's no context, no information provided, no details, nothing.  That's like asking: what should I drive (Subaru, Freightliner, or BMX).

Comment: Please do not bicker in comments. If you wish to discuss the merits of an answer, please do so in chat.